# How shall escape `>` in an edge label?

Tags: graphviz, dot

In my dot file

```
stdin_in -> file_out [label=<<font color="blue">tee >/dev/null</font>>];
```

`tee >/dev/null` is supposed to be the text of the label, but it contains `>` which is a special character, so `dot` complains about it. What shall I do instead? Thanks.

Comment: You need to give more context. Is that supposed to be a HTML-like label? Is any app outside graphviz producing this line?

Comment: @vaettchen thanks. it is quite flexible, and not supposed to be a HTML-like label. I used HTML like code only for adding color to the label, and didn't find other way to add the color (I am a beginner). Although my question is self contained, if you are interested, there is more context here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53421930/how-can-i-adjust-the-nodes-in-this-dot-program-into-a-2-by-3-table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the text in quotation marks; changing the line to

```
stdin_in -> file_out[ label = "tee > /dev/null" fontcolor = "blue" ];
```

produces the desired result:

[image]