# How can I adjust the nodes in this dot program into a 2 by 3 table?

Tags: graphviz, dot

I use graphviz to draw a diagram.

[image]

The placement of the nodes are not ideal. I would like the six nodes to be roughly placed in a 2 by 3 table:

```
file_in   stdin_in     string_in

file_out  stdout_out   variable_out
```

I have tried to add weights to some edges but still fails to move the nodes into such a table. See my dot program below. Thanks.

```
digraph G {

/* directly betw inputs */
node [color=black]
string_in -> stdin_in [label="redirection"];
 file_in -> stdin_in [label="redirection"];
 stdin_in -> file_in [label="device file /dev/stdin, or arg -", weight=8];
 stdin_in -> string_in [label="xargs"]; 

/* directly betw outputs */
node [color=red]
edge [color=red]
  stdout_out -> file_out [label="redirection" fontcolor="red"];
  file_out -> stdout_out [label="/dev/stdout or arg -" fontcolor="red"];

/* directly from input to output */
edge [color=blue]
 stdin_in -> stdout_out [label="cat or tee" fontcolor="blue" weight=8];
 stdin_in -> file_out [label = "tee > /dev/null" fontcolor = "blue"]; 
 string_in -> stdout_out [label="echo -n" fontcolor="blue" weight=2];
 file_in -> stdout_out [label="cat" fontcolor="blue"];
 file_in -> file_out [label="none" fontcolor="blue"];
 string_in -> variable_out [label="assignment" fontcolor="blue"];

/* directly from output to input */
edge [color=green]
 stdout_out -> stdin_in [label="pipe" fontcolor="green"];
 stdout_out -> file_in  [label="process substitution"  fontcolor="green"];
 stdout_out -> string_in [label="command substitution"  fontcolor="green"];
 file_out -> file_in [label="none"  fontcolor="green"];
 variable_out -> string_in [label="parameter expansion"  fontcolor="green"];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key point here is using `rank = same`; I have added this instruction at the top of your code. I have also increased the distance between the two rank levels so that there is more space for the edge labels. I have also changed the weights you had given to the edges in order to have a matrix like appearance.

Two more things I would recommend:

- rather than the HTML-like syntax for the node, use the standard graphviz format; matter of taste, but I find it easier to read and it is more flexible, see ([How shall escape `>` in an edge label?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53421641/how-shall-escape-in-an-edge-label)),
- when creating edges from nodes lower in the hierarchy to higher ones, don't use `b->a`, rather write `a->b[dir="back"]`; this avoids graphviz getting confused when the number of nodes increases

I have not completely edited the file, as it is not strictly necessary for the two items just mentioned - here the job I have done:

```
digraph G {

# layout
ranksep = 2
{ rank = same; file_in stdin_in string_in }
{ rank = same; file_out stdout_out variable_out }

/* directly betw inputs */
node [color=black]
 string_in -> stdin_in [label="redirection"];
 file_in -> stdin_in [label="redirection"];
 stdin_in -> file_in [label="device file /dev/stdin, or arg -"] 
 stdin_in -> string_in [label="xargs"]; 

/* directly betw outputs */
node [color=red]
edge [color=red]
  stdout_out -> file_out [label=<<font color="red">redirection</font>>];
  file_out -> stdout_out [label=<<font color="red">/dev/stdout or arg -</font>>];

/* directly from input to output */
edge [color=blue]
 stdin_in -> stdout_out [label=<<font color="blue">cat or tee</font>> weight = 10];
 # stdin_in -> file_out [label=<<font color="blue">tee /dev/null</font>>]; 
 stdin_in -> file_out[ label = "tee > /dev/null" fontcolor = "blue" ];
 string_in -> stdout_out [label=<<font color="blue">echo -n</font>> ];
 file_in -> stdout_out [label=<<font color="blue">cat</font>> ];
 file_in -> file_out [label = "none" fontcolor = "blue" weight = 10];
 string_in -> variable_out [label = "assignment" fontcolor = "blue" weight = 10 ];

/* directly from output to input */
edge [color=green]
 stdout_out -> stdin_in [label=<<font color="green">pipe</font>>];
 stdout_out -> file_in  [label=<<font color="green">process substitution</font>>];
 stdout_out -> string_in [label=<<font color="green">command substitution</font>>];
 file_in -> file_out [label="none" fontcolor="green" dir = back ];
 variable_out -> string_in [label=<<font color="green">parameter expansion</font>>];
}
```

which gives you

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! :) If I may ask, (1) Is it correct that `rank` is used for ensuring the nodes with the same rank are always in the same row?  (2) Is there no similar way to ensure nodes always in the same column, and the only  way is by adjusting edge weights?  (3) "when creating edges from nodes lower in the hierarchy to higher ones, don't use b->a, rather write a->b[dir="back"]; this avoids graphviz getting confused when the number of nodes increases". What kind of confusion is it? Thanks

Comment: To your questions: (1) in principle yes, `graphviz` needs to betoldwhat you wnat to haveon the same level - (2) There are other ways but depends upon the context - (3) `b->a` tells `graphviz` that `b` is hierarchically above `a` whixh may be contrary to what you want; in most cases, the context will rectify this but I have had situations where one edge in the wrong direction completely messed up the graph; as "good practice" keep the hierarchicalorder and the direction of the arrow separate

Comment: Thanks. To ensure nodes always in the same column, "there are other ways but depends upon the context". If I may ask, what are some other ways commonly used? Is there no way like `rank` which can enforce that?

Comment: Sorry but thi is really not so easy. Just a few items to check: Make sure you declare your nodes in the right order - `graphviz` draws them as they are declared. Quite often, invisible edges help to maintain order. [Subgraphs](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/Gallery/directed/cluster.html) can be a kind of last resort. But "no size fits all".

Comment: Thanks. Just in case as a backup plan, I am also trying to figure out a way to manually adjust the SVG file originally created by GraphViz,  in Inkscape or similar software. If you happen to know something about that, I'd appreciate your consideration too: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/483314/can-i-drag-a-node-without-breaking-the-edges-in-svg-file-in-inkscape